# SQL query to return 'name of day' using 'day of year'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I'm trying to write a *MSSQL* query that will return the name of the day (e.g. `Monday, Tuesday`...) using the supplied day of year (e.g. `1 for 1st of January, 2 for 2nd of January`).

```
SELECT DATENAME(dy, '2016-03-01') - returns 61

SELECT DATENAME(dw, '2016-03-01') - returns Tuesday

SELECT DATENAME(dw, 61) - returns Saturday
```

I want my 3rd query to return the correct day name (Tuesday in this instance), using the supplied day of year (61 in this instance). I understand that the problem is to do with the date portion in `DATENAME`(`datepart, date`), as it is in the incorrect date format but I do not have the full date, only the day of year.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @day_of_year int

SELECT @day_of_year = 61
SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(DAY, @day_of_year - 1, '2016-01-01'))
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! :) Unfortunately all the data I have is in format of 'day of year' (e.g. 61, 214, 303...) and I want to figure out what the name of the day is for the given day of year...